# Verificar o numero de cópias que foram impressas

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

Olá, tenho uma tabela que ao ser impressa gera um registro em um txt dizendo o usuário que imprimiu, em qual máquina, em qual impressora, qual foi o documento e quando. Porém gostaria de registrar também o numero de cópias, mas não faço a ideia de como.

Código que pega as informações do computador:

```
Declare Function GetComputerName& Lib "kernel32" Alias "GetComputerNameA" (ByVal lbbuffer As String, nSize As Long)
Public Declare Function GetUserName Lib "advapi32.dll" Alias "GetUserNameA" (ByVal lpBuffer As String, nSize As Long) As Long
Declare Function WNetGetUser Lib "mpr.dll" Alias "WNetGetUserA" (ByVal lpName As String, ByVal lpUserName As String, lpnLength As Long) As Long

Function deMAQUINA() As String
Dim Buffer As String * 256
Dim BuffLen As Long
Dim lngX As Long
Dim strCompName As String
BuffLen = 255
If GetComputerName(Buffer, BuffLen) Then deMAQUINA = Left(Buffer, BuffLen)
End Function

Function deUSUARIO() As String
Dim Buffer As String * 256
Dim BuffLen As Long
BuffLen = 256
If GetUserName(Buffer, BuffLen) Then deUSUARIO = Left(Buffer, BuffLen - 1)
End Function
```

Código que registra:

```
 Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean)

    Dim vUsuario As String, vMaquina As String
    vUsuario = deUSUARIO()
    vMaquina = deMAQUINA()

    Open "\\Caminho\do\arquivo.txt" For Append As #2

        Print #2, "O usuário: " & vUsuario & " | pela Máquina: " & vMaquina & " | pela impressora: " & ActivePrinter & " | Imprimiu o documento " & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "| no dia: " & Now

    Close #2

    Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\OBSOLETO\" & Left(ActiveWorkbook.Name, 8) & ".txt" For Append As #3

        Print #3, "O usuário: " & vUsuario & " | pela Máquina: " & vMaquina & " | pela impressora: " & ActivePrinter & " | Imprimiu o documento " & ActiveWorkbook.Name & "| no dia: " & Now

    Close #3

End Sub
```

Se alguém souber, por favor, poderia em ajudar?

Comment: Não poderia colocar uma planilha ai, com uma tabela por usuário para ir somando um contador a cada impressão, ou registrado numa linha cada impressão e gerar uma outra planilha com relatório?:

Comment: Imagine se o usuário imprimir 3 cópias e guardar com ele. Ele acaba de burlar o registro, pois ira aparecer que foi uma impressa, mas ele tem 3.

Comment: E se vc bloquear a impressão e criar uma rotina que o usuário somente pode imprimir ao clicar em um botão? Daí terá o controle de quantas cópias. O que acha?

Comment: Nesse caso eu saberia te ajudar como fazer tenho uma rotina pronta que faz isso. =)

Comment: Eu até gostaria, mas os usuários ficariam irritados já que eles estão acostumados a usar o "Ctrl + P" , então eu tento manter o registro como se nada tivesse sido alterado na planilha. O ideal é algo que eu pegue quantas foram impressas mesmo :)

Comment: `Ctrl+P` continuaria a funcionar, só que iria imprimir automático! rs Mas entendo. Se descobrir posta ai. Abs

Comment: Obrigado mesmo assim @Evert, postarei sim.

Answer (score 1):

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforePrint(Cancel As Boolean) 
If ActiveSheet.CodeName = "Sheet1" Then 
    With Sheet1.Range("A1") 
        Select Case .Value 
        Case Is > 0 
            .Range("A1").Value = .Range("A1") + 1 

        Case Else ' cell is empty
            .Range("A1").Value = 1 

        End Select 
    End With 
End If 
End Sub
```

Você pode utilizar um contador e incrementar uma célula a cada nova impressão.
verifique se consegue com esse código implementar o seu!

Comment: Mas neste caso ele marca somente que imprimiu, isso eu já tenho, preciso saber quantas foram copiadas, tipo se o usuário imprimiu 3 cópias de uma vez só.